# How to upload Delphi IPA to Apple app store

Tags: ios, delphi, ipa

How do I upload my iOS IPA file (made by Delphi 11.3) to the Apple app store?

I cannot find Application Uploader and TestFlight does not seem to have this capability.

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Comment: That got it uploaded. If you want to post Apple Transporter as the answer I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `Dave Nottage`'s answer of using [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12), you can also upload a build to appstoreconnect using the [`xcrun`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcrun/) command line utility.

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file location/to/App.ipa --username username --password app-password
```

It could be useful in situations in which you want to upload a build from a script or when you don't have access to the Transporter app.

For the `--username` flag I use my Apple ID.

For the `--password` flag I set up an app password at https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and use that.